# Bring Sypder IDE graphics window to front

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

I have spyder 3.0 running on a Windows 8 machine.  Whenever I call a new figure for plotting it automatically goes to the back of my windows. Is there a way to have it plot on top of other existing windows as it does on my Linux laptop?

Thanks, 
A

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) This is not a problem with Spyder but with Matplotlib. However, we plan to add a workaround for it in a future release.

Comment: Thanks Carlos for all your work.  Like I said it works wonderfully on my Linux machine.  I will  wait for the update.

Comment: Carlos Cordoba, if you want to copy and paste this comment as an answer I can mark this as solved.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the offer. I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This is not a problem with Spyder but with Matplotlib. However, there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6384) in Matplotlib that will fix it (perhaps in Matplotlib 2.1).